# Local error per unit step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, truncation-error

The solution of the *ODE* $$ y' = f(t,y)$$ is being seeked.

Let $u_{m}$ be the numerical solution of a one step method and $y(t_m)$ its true solution. The *local error*  $e_{loc} $ is then defined as  $$e_{loc}(t_m):= y(t_m) - u_m$$
Related to this this definition, is the *local error per unit step*, defined as
$$e_{loc}(t+h)/h, \quad h \text{  being the step size.}$$
What is the deeper meaning of the defintion of the *local error per unit step?*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I believe that when comparing various errors, they be "normalized" in some way so the comparison is reasonable (e.g., comparing an error over a length of $1$ compared to over a length of a billion doesn't usually provide much useful information).  Dividing by $h$ means that the result is what the local error is roughly on average per unit change of $t$.

Comment: Could you add more context? One area where this is important is with adaptive step sizes. One criterion to control the step size is to hold the "local error per unit step" constant at the level of the provided tolerances, if $e_{loc}(t,h)=C(t)h^{p+1}+...$, one would strive to get $e_{loc}(t,h)/h=C(t)h^{p}=\epsilon$ so that the global error computes approximately as $\sum C(t_k)h_k^{p+1}=\epsilon\sum h_k=\epsilon(t_{final}-t_{init})$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very quick answers so far. It is a very general context actually. It is used in a book for the analysis of the consistency of a general one step method for solving numerically ode's.

Comment: Unfortunately, the book is written in german. The author is Karl Strehmel, from his book "Numerik gewöhnlicher Differentialgleichungen" page 24.
https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783834818478

Answer (score 1):

The local error measures how much error you make taking one step of length $h$.  If you cut the step size in half you need to take twice as many steps to cover a given distance, so unless the local error is cut in half as well you are doing worse to take the shorter steps.  Dividing by the step size normalizes this, so the local error per unit step is an approximation of the error you make while you advance the independent variable by $1$ regardless of the step size you take.